# Какие права нужны для MySQL-пользователей для работы из PHP-скрипта

Tags: mysql

Если база будет использоваться PHP скриптами, на добавление, обновление, удаление, т.е. стандартный многопользовательский сайт.

Можно пример как их выставить, начиная с создания нового пользователя?

Comment: Как думаю так и пишу. Вы прочтите ваш вопрос, смогли бы ответить если бы не знали контекста?

Comment: `GRANT ALL ON database.* TO user@host`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создать пользователя удобно при помощи оператора `CREATE USER`

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Здесь создается MySQL-пользователь `user` с паролем `password`, который будет иметь доступ к базе данных только с локальной машины. Если база данных расположена на отдельном хосте, то вам следует создавать сетевого пользователя. Лучше, если вы явно зададите домен, с которого будут идти обращения к базе данных

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'php-domain.host.ru' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Если это невозможно или таких хостов слишком много, можно разрешить доступ с любых хостов

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Если у вас еще не создана база данных для пользователя, создать ее можно при помощи оператора `CREATE DATABASE`

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `dbname`
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET `utf8` COLLATE `utf8_unicode_ci`;
```

Здесь создается база данных с именем `dbname` и кодировкой по умолчанию UTF-8.

Теперь можно дать права доступа пользователю `user` на базу данных `dbname`

```
GRANT
  SELECT,
  LOCK TABLES,
  INSERT,
  UPDATE,
  DELETE,
  CREATE,
  DROP,
  INDEX,
  ALTER
ON `dbname`.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

Последним GRANT-оператором, мы разрешили CRUD-операции (вставка, удаление, редактирование, чтение), а также создание, удаление, изменение, блокировку и индексирование таблиц.